# nHibernate generating correct SQL, but returning empty rows

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following ICriteria query,

```
public override IQueryable<ApplicationVehicleSummary> GetQuery(ISession session)
    {
        ICriteria results = session.CreateCriteria<Part>()
           .Add(Restrictions.Eq("PartNumber", _partNumber))
           .CreateCriteria("Applications")
           .CreateAlias("Vehicles", "vehicle", global::NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
           .SetProjection(Projections.Property("vehicle.Make"),
           Projections.Property("vehicle.Model"),
           Projections.Property("vehicle.Type"),
           Projections.Property("vehicle.Engine"),
           Projections.Property("vehicle.ProductionStart"),
           Projections.Property("vehicle.ProductionEnd"))
           .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ApplicationVehicleSummary>());

       return results.List<ApplicationVehicleSummary>().AsQueryable();
    }
```

And it produces the following SQL.

```
SELECT vehicle2_.Make            as y0_,
   vehicle2_.Model           as y1_,
   vehicle2_.Type            as y2_,
   vehicle2_.Engine          as y3_,
   vehicle2_.ProductionStart as y4_,
   vehicle2_.ProductionEnd   as y5_
FROM   Parts this_
   inner join Applications applicatio1_
     on this_.PartId = applicatio1_.PartId
   inner join VehiclesToApplications vehicles5_
     on applicatio1_.ApplicationId = vehicles5_.ApplicationId
   inner join Vehicles vehicle2_
     on vehicles5_.VehicleId = vehicle2_.VehicleId
WHERE  this_.PartNumber = '0500-252' /* @p0 */
```

When I run the query from my app nHibernate returns the right amount of rows but all the fields are null or empty. But when I take the SQL it has generated (from nhibernate profiler) and run it on my db it returns the correct results.

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146637/return-entity-via-projection-query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use same names as a fields of , or specify mapping explicitly:

```
.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
               .add( Projections.property("vehicle.Model"), "fieldName1" )
               .add( Projections.property("vehicle.Type"), "fieldName2" )
```

or use attributes

also check this project [Fluent nHibernate](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/)

Comment: This worked great. 
I have been thrown in the deep end with nHibernate, but with a little bit of help from you guys I'm starting to get to grips with it.

Thanks,