# NHibernate 3 + NamedQuery + BinaryBlob properties?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have to maintain/support a source code using Nhibernate (3.3).
In one place (statistics processing) I have to load entities that represent jobs on images and the final image is in a Blob in the DB:

```
_dbSess = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
   IQuery dbQuery = _dbSess.GetNamedQuery("GetReadyClientFilesForOper");
   dbQuery.SetString("operId", UserId);
   dbQuery.SetDateTime("fdate", from);
   dbQuery.SetDateTime("tdate", to);                
   cltFiles = dbQuery.List<ClientFile>();
```

the Query is :

```
    query name="GetReadyClientFilesForOper"
    ![CDATA[select clt from ClientFile clt where (clt.Status = 5 or clt.Status = 6) and 
     (clt.ReassignedTo = :operId or (clt.ReassignedTo is null and clt.DispatchedTo  =operId))
    and clt.ReadyDate >= :fdate and clt.ReadyDate <= :tdate
    order by clt.AccountInfo.Oid]]
/query
```

The problem occurs when the query gets executed because the ClientFile contains properties like:

`<property name="PdfContent" column="RESULT_PDF" type="BinaryBlob" />`

I am pretty sure that this property get loaded from the DB (and I don't need it at the moment) and it takes a huge amount of memory.

When the `ClientFile` object get loaded by `NHibernate` (not through the `NamedQuery`), the property is not loaded because considered as a Lazy one...

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the file i suggest:

You could also use the AliasToBean ResultTransformer, which automatically maps the values returned from the query to the properties of a given type. This approach requires that the aliases used in the query map directly to properties of the given type. For example:

```
IList<Foo> foos = session.CreateQuery(
   "select f.Name as Name, f.Value as Value from Foo f")
   .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Foo>())
   .List<Foo>();
```

Editing your named query, projecting what you need and calling as:

```
cltFiles = _dbSess.GetNamedQuery("GetReadyClientFilesForOper")
    .SetString("operId", UserId)
    .SetDateTime("fdate", from)
    .SetDateTime("tdate", to)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ClientFile>())
    .List<ClientFile>()
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146637/return-entity-via-projection-query)

Then you can load the binary data.

Or read [this](http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties), to load all entity with LazyLoad Properties.

Comment: Is it really the only solution to make a lazy load of a BinaryBlob property?

Comment: Check the second approach, looks more better for your requeriment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried also the approch by setting the BinayBlob as lazy=true (the article in the refenrece). When I call the forllowing code (my named query converted into Criteria)

```
 _dbSess.CreateCriteria<ClientFile>()
 .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Eq("Status", 5), Restrictions.Eq("Status", 6)))
 .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Eq("ReassignedTo", UserId), Restrictions.And(Restrictions.IsNull("ReassignedTo"), Restrictions.Eq("DispatchedTo", UserId))))
 .Add(Restrictions.And(Restrictions.Ge("ReadyDate", from), Restrictions.Le("ReadyDate", to)))
 .List<ClientFile>();
```

the Blobs doesn't get loaded (Youpi!) but the other ClientFile lists and sets, also tagged as lazy, not loaded. The problem now is when I try to access one of these IList or ICollections they are not automatically loaded by NHibernate !

Comment: In the reference Ayende says: There isn't a way to specify this for criteria API right now.

Comment: In fact between this call and the use of lazy loaded properties there was a session.Close() -> I eliminated it but I see that NHibernate (Output in Visual Studio) doesn't make any call to the DB to initialize the property... I found the following code var o = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession().Get<ClientFile>(this.Oid); NibernateUtil.Initialize(o.nhDocStats); return o.nhDocStats; that correctly returns the property initialized but the problem it reloads the entire object...